# how to change UI language to english in eclipse on linux

Tags: eclipse

Default language in system is Russian. I tried to add in VM arguments

> -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

but it don't help me.

Comment: Can't test easily at the moment, but try running it from a terminal using a line like: `LANG=en_US.utf-8 eclipse` (i.e. set the LANG environment variable first). Might look at any other environment vars that are language-specific (type `set | grep ru` to look for possible "suspects")